# Class with alternative name

Tags: java, class, classloader, classname

I have a javaprogramm that uses a libary, where that packagenames change with almost every new version.

I want my programm to run on more than one version of the libary. I thought it might be possible to create an aliasname for a class:

```
my.class.????.path -> my.class.path
```

I can get the ???? part by using class.getName() and split, i just need a way to tell a classloader to link the class *my.class.???.path* with another path, so i can use *import me.class.path* in the class loaded with my classloader.

I have a version where i have many files, that use diffrent imports and i load them depending on what libaryversion is used, but that is using more resources and i want my programm to stay small.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Leo

Comment: Stop using that library.

Comment: Try to find another library...

Comment: Just curious, what library are you writing of? It's not really sensible to change the package names (?!?), and therefore the whole structure of the library `with almost every release`...

Comment: @StackOverflowException Im using classes in the libary that are not made to be used, thats y they change their names, and i need acces to them to get my programm working.

Comment: Im using [bukkit](http://bukkit.org/), i need to get access to classes of the api that are not supposed to be used.

Comment: But you know which classes you wan't for every version? If not, I doubt you can afford scanning all classes and determining which to use on startup...

Comment: @StackOverflowException I think i've actually found a way to do this. I won't use a URLClassLoader, but a classloader that loads the bytes, and then replaces the FullQualifiedClassNames that are in the bytecode, bevore loading the class to the JVM.

Comment: @CoderCloud: That sounds like a lot of overhead for a minecraft mod. You really need access to that API? Ever thought about asking at their forum (supposed they have one)?

Comment: @StackOverflowException I posted some threads there, but never got a reply. I acctually got this working, i could add a second fqcn to java.lang.System. I loaded the classbytes in my classloader with a ZipFile stream and the made my method to replace all used instances of my custom name with java.lang.System and the bytelength indicator in front of the name.

Comment: @StackOverflowException Other developers use a seperate file for every version of bukkit, but i think it would be better like this, so the plugin won't break with every minor update.

Answer (score 0):

### You can't.

Or at least it's not that trivial/sensible.
Take a look at this very simple Java program:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println(r.nextInt());
    }

}
```

Using `javac Simple.java` will yield the following `.class` file (`javap -c Simple`):

```
Compiled from "Simple.java"
public class Simple {
  public Simple();
  Code:
     0: aload_0       
     1: invokespecial #1 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
     0: new           #2 // class java/util/Random
     3: dup           
     4: invokespecial #3 // Method java/util/Random."<init>":()V
     7: astore_1      
     8: getstatic     #4 // Field    java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    11: aload_1       
    12: invokevirtual #5 // Method java/util/Random.nextInt:()I
    15: invokevirtual #6 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
    18: return        
}
```

As you can see, the class names are fully qualified, so without manipulation of the bytecode with libraries as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/index.html), you won't be going to change them.

**But**, it **is** possible:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class cl = Class.forName("java.util.Random");
        Object r = cl.newInstance();
        Method nextIntMethod = cl.getMethod("nextInt");
        int randomInt = (Integer) nextIntMethod.invoke(r);
        System.out.println(randomInt);
    }

}
```

Though that way is really cumbersome.

Note that the solution using reflection grew from 2 significant lines to 5.
Additionally, you still need to get the FQCN's by version. Otherwise it will blow up!

Comment: I know how to get the FQCN's. Im using reflection to get a class and then i can split the classname to extract the package.

Comment: I know how to get the FQCN's. Im using reflection to get a class and then i can split the classname to extract the package. I thought it might be possible by using classloaders. I already got a classloader where i can change the class thats going to be searched for (by overriding the loadClass() and findClass() methods), but then i get a NoClassDefFoundError which means that there was no ClassDefinition found. If i would know how to override the method that asingns the ClassDefinition to the ClassName, i could do it. But the exact path of the Error is not shown in the exception.